# Resource Estimation for Ion Trap Architecture

Tags: error-correction, fault-tolerance, ion-trap-quantum-computing

Most resource estimation papers (computing physical qubit count, algorithm run time, power consumption, etc.) target the superconducting qubit architecture. Some examples include

- **How to factor 2048 bit RSA integers in 8 hours using 20 million noisy qubits**: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.09749
- **Surface codes: Towards practical large-scale quantum computation**: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0928.pdf

Are there some recent reviews targetting resource estimates performed for algorithms on trapped ion quantum computers?

If not, then what would be the possible differences that need to be taken into account when performing a resource estimation for fault-tolerant algorithms on the ion trap architecture as compared to the superconducting case?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but still directly relevant: Here's a research paper on resource estimation for generic multi-core QC architectures. I claim this is relevant because Trapped ion-systems are more likely to be multi-core instead of monolithic -- It's quite difficult to control more than ~100 ions in a single magnetic potential.

https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08861